# React-vr app on Heroku don't load client.bundle

Tags: node.js, heroku, react-360

I have a web app on Heroku based on React-vr

Locally works fine, but once I've pushed to Heroku loading the VR html page I see in logs than calling 
"./client.bundle?platform=vr"
I retrieve the 404 error (Not found), even if with bash I see the "client.js" file is present

I've also tryed to call in my source "./client.bundle.js?platform=vr", but I get the same issue.

Anybody can suggest me please a solution?
Many thanks

Comment: Could you add some documentation/explanation?

Comment: What do you need to know?

It seems that on Heroku the app doesn't find the - existing - js file (in the folder where VR app runs: "/vr/client.bundle")

It's impossible locally to run bundle (already included in my Node version and automatically done while deploying)

If you need more infos, please request it

Comment: Solved.
Deleting node_modules folder and running again npm install solved this issue